# Orchard - Contact Form rtl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, right-to-left

I wonder how to convert "Contact Form - 0.9.4" module or "oForms - 1.8.1." or "Custom Forms"  to right to left script?

Comment: What's different about contact forms? Don't you just need a rtl theme?

Comment: I already installed the unique existing theme for rtl, as I know that rtl in Orchard is till now poor in ressources, and since there are many kinds of forms I would know which one offers the most compliant features.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. Do you just mean that they work well with an existing RTL theme? The module should not have anything specific to do. All should happen in the theme. If you have to override a few templates from the module in the theme, that's a possibility, but in any case, 100% of the RTL work is likely to happen in the theme.

Comment: Ok, well receipt, thank you Bertrand. As I am new to Orchard, and to avoid making a wrong way to go back after, I read many reviews on the different modules that left me even more hesitant, I would like to call your experience and ask you to advise me to choose between these 3 modules types: "Custom Forms", "Contact Form - 0.9.4" and "oForms - 1.8.1". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Custom Forms: http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha.

Comment: That's a very good link, thank you very much, but could not find there how to make the form writes from right to left.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the RTL theme... I thought you had problems with those Forms with the last version of Orchard. The RTL theme doesn't works?

Comment: Yes it does but there is still work to be done. Now as said Bertrand above, I see that rtl is related to theme not to Forms, I have to choose between Forms kinds, you proposed in your link the "Custom Forms", and I found on the web [Contact Form - 0.9.4](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.CyberStride.Contacts) and [oForms - 1.8.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/04/24/webmatrix-add-contact-us-page-with-email-to-your-orchard-website.aspx)